# g++ "generator: No such file or directory" - which version of GCC supports the <generator> header?

Tags: g++, generator, c++23

I've built GCC 13.2.0 that I believe has quite good support for c++23.

I'm trying to compile some code that would use the c++23 std::generator.

For example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator

c++23 should have the generator header: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator

```cpp
#include <generator>
```

However when I compile this with g++ I get the following error:

```
$ ~/opt/gcc/13.2.0/bin/g++ -Wall -std=c++23 generator.cpp -o generator
generator.cpp:3:10: fatal error: generator: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <generator>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My guess is that 13.2.0 does not yet have support for this feature, but I'm struggling to confirm that guess.  My question is, which version of GCC supports this feature?

I looked on this page:
https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html
but nothing stood out that would tell me the answer.

Also I looked on this page:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2023

Comment: The status you link to is for the compiler itself, not the standard library, which can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the helpful suggestion. I checked that page too but did not find an answer to my question.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23 says GCC 14 or newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to HolyBlackCat, I found the answer is GCC 14.

At the time of writing this, 14 is not yet ready for release, but with a bit of poking around on gcc web site I found this page that seems to confirm it:
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-14/changes.html

> Improved experimental support for C++23, including:
>
> ...
>
> The std::generator view for getting results from coroutines.
>
> ...